# What is the expected return of `useEffect` used for?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

In the React [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) for hooks they say:

> "This also allows you to handle out-of-order responses with a local
> variable inside the effect"

```
useEffect(() => {
  let ignore = false;

  async function fetchProduct() {
    const response = await fetch('http://myapi/product/' + productId);
    const json = await response.json();
    if (!ignore) setProduct(json);
  }
    
  fetchProduct();

  return () => { ignore = true };
}, [productId]);
```

[Demo app](https://codesandbox.io/s/jvvkoo8pq3)

Please help me understand this better by explaining:

1. Why is the return a function? `return () => { ignore = true };`
2. What is ignored used for in this example?

Thanks!

Comment: To ignore the API response. Whenever the input changes, state is set and hence useEffect runs again, which invokes a new API call. To ignore the old API call result, the returned function of `useEffect` sets the previous useEffect localvariable to false. This guarentess that the only the last rendered useEffect( and the API call that triggered along) and its result is stored.

Comment: In this article https://medium.com/hackernoon/avoiding-race-conditions-when-fetching-data-with-react-hooks-220d6fd0f663, you can see a good explanation of why return () => { ignore = true }; 
In a few words it is to avoid race condition.

Answer (score 79):

**1. Why is the return a function? `return () => { ignore = true };`**

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

> **Why did we return a function from our effect?** This is the optional cleanup mechanism for effects. Every effect may return a function that cleans up after it. This lets us keep the logic for adding and removing subscriptions close to each other. They’re part of the same effect!

and

> **When exactly does React clean up an effect?** React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts. However, as we learned earlier, effects run for every render and not just once. This is why React also cleans up effects from the previous render before running the effects next time. We’ll discuss why this helps avoid bugs and how to opt out of this behaviour in case it creates performance issues later below.

**2. What is ignored used for in this example?**

Initially in `useEffect` Hook `ignore` is set like, `let ignore = false;`.

When `fetchProduct` function executes it checks for `ignore` is `true` and accordingly sets `setProduct(json)`.

This means we have `state` called `product` and setting the value in `state` using `setProduct(json)`.

This `product` in state is used to render details on page.

**Note:** As `[productId]` is passed as second argument to `useEffect`, `fetchProduct` function will only get executes when `productId` changes.

See [optimizing performance by skipping effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).

Comment: My return function runs on page load so this makes no sense

Answer (score 67):

I will explain it here, as **it took me a while to understand** the explanations above, so I will try to make it simpler on others.

Answers for your questions: 
**1. Why is the return a function? `return () => { ignore = true };`** 
useEffect offers the use of return function, which is used for cleanup function purposes, OK!, **When do you need a clean up?** If u made a subscription for something, and u want to unsubscribe from it for example, you should add unsubscription logic in "return function" inside useEffect , instead of putting the logic in other places, that may cause a race condition!

**2. What is ignored used for in this example?**
The `ignore` is used as a flag that tells the function to ignore the api call or not. when is that used? when you have a race condition.

**[**example for a race condition** - *you can ignore this part of u are already familiar with race* conditions*]* For example u click in list of products, and when each product is clicked you will update the page with this product info, if u click quickly in the products for many times , the useEffect will be updated whenever `product_id` is changed, and at some point clicking on product1 [will call api for product1 ]then quickly product2 [will call api for product2 and retrieve data **causing -> setProduct(product2data)** ] while still data for product1 has just arrived **causing -> setProduct(product1data)** . This way we have product2 clicked ! but product1 data appears at page!!.

****BUTTTT WHAT THAT HAVE TO DO WITH `ignore` ??****
**[logic explanation]** 
`ignore` , my dear , tells the setProduct to ignore the old data, and not set it, this way we only will set the last clicked product, even if old data arrived later. 
**[code explanation]** 
1- first scenario : no races , product1 is clicked -> `ignore` is false , call api , retrieve data , if(`!ignore` ) -> will set product1 data , now clean up function will set `ignore` to true , congrats !.

2- second scenario -> race condition , product1 is clicked -> ignore is false, call api , [data still hasn't arrived] ,now product2 is clicked ignore is false , call api , data arrived , if(`!ignore` ) -> will set product2 data , clean up function will set ignore to true , product1 function data has arrived -> if(`!ignore` ) -> is false **OOOPS**, will not set product1 data "old data".

**AND THIS WAY WE WILL ALWAYS HAVE NEW DATA. CHEERRRRRRRRS :D**

Comment: I like the way you excitingly answered this as someone who just experienced the "Aha" moment

Comment: that's so great explanation, so helpful!

Comment: Could u explain why product2 data will set first? I see there is  async await inside useffect. Even I click product2, it still need to wait prosduct1 finished. Right? Do I misunderstand anything? Sorry, I new to learn react.

Comment: @FrogTuna product2 data may set first it may not - it's a race. Suppose the data from product1 call was very large and the data from product2 call was very small, it is possible the product2 call returns first even if it was called slightly later than product1 call. As you note, they are asynchronous calls meaning here that they get sent over the internet without waiting for each other to return first.

Comment: @GrahamHesketh I was also wondering same,  what if product1 data comes after clicking product2, will it not stop product2 data to update on UI?

Comment: Very helpful indeed!

Answer (score 13):

```js
// all imports
function myFunc() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // it prints when mouse moves
    const a = addEventListener('mouse', console.log('mouse moves')); 

    return () => {
      // whenever the component removes it will executes
      removeEventListener(a);
    };
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The return function is the **cleanup function**, or when the **user leaves the page** and the component will unmount. The array is the last part, and it is where you put the states that will update throughout the component's lifecycle.
[For more](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Answer (score 4):

we use a boolean flag called `ignore` to let our data fetching logic know about the state (mounted/unmounted) of the component.If the component did unmount, the flag should be set to true which results in preventing to set the component state after the data fetching has been asynchronously resolved eventually. when component is unmounted then "return" (second part of useEffect) is called. but in this case because of dependency [query] when query changes, our component is re-rendered, so sideEffect is re-initialized. Run [this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-dew-qi8yo) on your IDE then open Devtools in your browser like chrome and clear console then in input which the word react is written, add char 2 as fast as possible and then immediately remove char 2. check console to see what happened.

Comment: This answers OP's second question, and mine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` executes every render not once. When you want to clean up effects from the previous render before executing the subsequent effects that's time to return a function with clean up logic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For the second question **--What is ignored used for in this example? :**

It is used to ensure that the latest value of **productId** is the one that our state update will depend on, mainly when more than one request is being processed simultaneously. In this case, **ignore** value will be ***true*** after every request that is being processed sends a response except for the one where the URL contains the latest updated value of **productId**. (here in this case **ignore** will remain ***false***)

Now let's discuss the code above:

We know that useEffect runs the function declared in return before the next effect runs. Let's imagine that two changes in the value of **productId** happened so quickly (maybe due to a quick input typing which updates the value on every change). For the first update, the effect will run and set **ignore** to ***false***. Let's say that before the fetch request is successfully processed and response is assigned a value, the second change to **productId** happens. Here the function returned by our old effect will run and assign ***true*** to ignore, and right after that, the new effect related to the new value of **productId** will also run assigning ***false*** to **ignore** and proceed to the fetch request with our new **productId**. However, the value of **ignore*** for the old effect is now ***true***, which means that after getting a response the state update will be ignored ( ! ignore = false ). For the new effect if a successful response arrives with data and the code execution proceeds to the if statement before any change in **productId** value occurs, **ignore** will remain ***false*** (! ignore = true), and our state will be updated using the latest value of **productId**.