# want to know why componentWillUnmount execute when a component update

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import CounterOne from "./CounterOne";
function App() {
  const [display, setDisplay] = React.useState(true);
  return (
    <>
      {display && <CounterOne />}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setDisplay(!display);
        }}
      >
        display
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

CounterOne.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function CounterOne() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("component did update");
    return () => {
      console.log("component will unmount");
    };
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Count is {count}</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount(0);
        }}
      >
        reset
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount(count + 5);
        }}
      >
        Add 5
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount(count - 1);
        }}
      >
        Sub 1
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CounterOne;
```

When i hit the Add 5 or sub 1 button, the component re-render then in browser console it prints

**component will unmount**

**component did update**

i am confuse why will unmount part execute when the update of state taking place

Comment: See these help: 

You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup)

And [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKOQtGLT-Yk&ab_channel=TheNetNinja) is really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you change a state in a component, React will re-render the whole component. So the old component will be unmounted first, triggering the return callback in useEffect. When a new component is mounted, the logic inside useEffect will be triggered again, hence you see the "component did update" after the "component will unmount" message. More on useEffect here [What is the expected return of `useEffect` used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56800694/what-is-the-expected-return-of-useeffect-used-for).