# React Why do we use Clean up function in this example?

Tags: reactjs

what is the difference between when I use that clean-up function and I do not?
Apparently, there is no difference in the execution of the program and both produce the same result, so why do we use the clean-up function at all?

```
function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('True');
  const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
      alert('hello world');
    }, 1500);


       //CLEAN UP FUNCTION
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeOut);
    };
  }, []);




  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCheck(!check);
        }}
      >
        Change
      </button>
      <h2>{check ? 'true' : 'false'}</h2>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You won't be able to see it in your `App` directly. Try to put your timeout in a new Component, and from your app, having a state which mounts / unmounts your Component with the setTiemout, and you'll see what the use of the cleanup fonction :)
Without it, even if you unmount your Component, the timeout will still occurs

Comment: It is done in case that you unmount the component before the timeout has ended, so you can cancel it and prevent it from running if the component is no longer mounted.

Comment: I found this helpful OP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56800694/what-is-the-expected-return-of-useeffect-used-for

Answer (score 0):

like the name suggests, it's a cleanup function.

```
function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() =>
    setTimeout(() => { setShow(false) }, 100),
  []);

  return show ? <Counter/> : null;
}

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => 
    setInterval(() => setCounter(n => n+1), 100),
  []);

  return <div>{count}</div>
}
```

if you don't cleanup the `setInterval()`, it will continue running after Counter is unmounted, and cause a memory leak.
Same for `setTimeout()` - it could try to set state after unmount, causing an error.