# reactjs: need help to understand the below code

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I came accross this code

```
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setTimeout(() => setCount(count + 1), 1000);
    return () => setTimeout(timerId);
  });
```

I know useEffect syntax as

```
useEffect(() => {
    something...which is executed
  });
```

but in the code i see its returning inside useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    ....
    return () => 
  });
```

As per my understanding how its different from just

```
  useEffect(() => {
    //const timerId = setTimeout(() => setCount(count + 1), 1000);
    setTimeout(() => setCount(count + 1), 1000);
    //return () => setTimeout(timerId);
  });
```

i am bit confused how this works

Comment: This answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56800694/what-is-the-expected-return-of-useeffect-used-for ?

Comment: `setTimeout(timerId)` doesn't make much sense. Are you sure it's not `clearTimeout(timderId)`

Comment: Never use useEffect without dependency arrary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56800795/5268235) the return of the `useEffect` is to clean up and, the returned function is run when the component is unmounted or every time it is rendered.

So to answer how is

```
useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setTimeout(() => setCount(count + 1), 1000);
    return () => setTimeout(timerId);
});
```

different from

```
useEffect(() => {
    //const timerId = setTimeout(() => setCount(count + 1), 1000);
    setTimeout(() => setCount(count + 1), 1000);
    //return () => setTimeout(timerId);
});
```

I think it is the confusion on the part of the Author of the first snippet. I think the intended code was

```
useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setTimeout(() => setCount(count + 1), 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timerId);
});
```

Since the timeout is bound to the `window`(global scope), the author meant to clear the previous timeout on each render or when the component is unmounted.

Comment: That code where OP came accross is probably https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-provider-example-hl4e4f?file=/src/App.js:846-945 ..  i came across this as well and went googling for the purpose of setTimeout(timerId) since to my knowledge it should be clearTimeout

Answer (score 0):

If you return function inside useEffect, it's called `cleanup function` This function is executed when the component is unmounted.

What the author was trying to do is that clear the timer when the component is unmounted but, I think the code you came across kinda confusing anyway

I think it should be like this..

```js
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setTimeout(() => setCount((count) => count + 1), 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timerId);
  }, []);
```